# What is an example of incompatible rulings on a matter (i.e., if we follow one ruling, we must disobey the other)?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-philosophy

When two groups/individuals argue regarding any matter, I find always a mid-way solution that is on the safe side.  For example:

1. One person says: during ablution, one should wash their hands three times.
2. Another says: No, you wash your hands at least one time.

Washing one's hands "three times" is better as it is accepted by both the individuals.  However, I have read a Hadith saying that "you should do at least one time".  Even then, three times is on safe side logically.

Are there any example matters where there is no safe side in?